# Layer from many tif + twf files using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have 1000 .tif and .tfw files.

Example of tfw files.

```
0.070
0.000
0.000
-0.070
586100.075
1856900.475
```

I want to make a GeoServer layer from this files. I've tried to use ImageMosaic or  WorldImage, but got error:

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:path/to/directory
```

How should I compile this files to layer?

Answer (score 1):

Your files are lacking projection information that GeoServer needs to produce the mosaic. I wrote a [blog post](https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools,/projections,/itches/2017/10/20/adding-prj.html) about how to solve this by adding a `.prj` file to each of the `tif`/`tfw` pairs.

Or you could use `gdal_transform` to convert to GeoTiffs with the projection set directly (`-s_crs`).